# Password protecting folder in windows using a .bat/ .exe file: is it such a bad practice?

Tags: passwords

I have been browsing the internet looking for simple ways to password protect a folder in Windows 7 without any extra software nor BitLocker.

I have found several places that state that using a .bat file (and then converting it to an .exe file to avoid people opening it in a text editor and making sense of it) would allow this.

However something tells me this is a not very secure system.

I share here some of the typical .bat file's code they claim to work and password protect the folder:

```
@ECHO OFF
if EXIST "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}" goto UNLOCK
if NOT EXIST Private goto MDPrivate
:CONFIRM
echo Are you sure to lock this folder? (Y/N)
set/p "cho=>"
if %cho%==Y goto LOCK
if %cho%==y goto LOCK
if %cho%==n goto END
if %cho%==N goto END
echo Invalid choice.
goto CONFIRM
:LOCK
ren Private "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}"
attrib +h +s "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}"
echo Folder locked
goto End
:UNLOCK
echo Enter password to Unlock Your Secure Folder
set/p "pass=>"
if NOT %pass%== wonderhowtogoto FAIL
attrib -h -s "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}"
ren "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}" Private
echo Folder Unlocked successfully
goto End
:FAIL
echo Invalid password
goto end
:MDPrivate
md Private
echo Private created successfully
goto End
:End
```

Would this be easy to crack after we export it into an .exe file? What if I encrypt the .exe file for extra security?

And also, would the folder need to be hidden for this "trick" to work?
What are those keys like `21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D`?

Thanks very much for throwing some light over here.

Comment: Just cheap tricks that achieve nothing. Useful for a bit of fun on school computers at a young age perhaps. What were your sources? Do we need to correct them, or were they just "for fun"?

Comment: "(and then converting it to an .exe file to avoid people opening it in a text editor and making sense of it)" This won't stop people looking at it. The moment they realise the exe doesn't run properly they'll open it in a text editor to find out why and see it's a renamed batch file.

Comment: Nitpick: `if NOT %pass%== wonderhowtogoto FAIL` -> `if NOT %pass%== wonderhowto goto FAIL`

Comment: @Pharap converting not renaming, probably it just creates a batch file in %temp% and then runs it.

Comment: @immibis In that case the goalposts just shift slightly - the plaintext of the batch file is recoverable with the right tool.

Comment: @Pharap : Where I think "Notepad" fits the definition of "right tool" (there will be a lot of crap as well, but the text should be directly viewable) - unless  of course the "convert to exe" ROT13 encodes the text.

Comment: @MartinBonner Then we're just back to my earlier point of looking at it with a text editor. (I find Notepad++ easier for that because it can render the non-printable chars, though aparently Linux has [`strings`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2497183/1377706) which should do the job too.)

Comment: @jakekimdsΨ to be perfectly honest the whole thing could be summed up as `goto FAIL`

Comment: are you the only one using your account on your machine? (do the other users have their own account?) if so you can just restrict the folder to yourself

Comment: I've actually encountered this in the wild once and it was very easy to figure out what was going on and exfiltrate the data. Just use a VeraCrypt volume with a clever name, like `thumbs.db` or `.DS_Store`, and you'll keep out everyone except state-sponsored actors.

Comment: Nice .DS_Store trick. (:

Comment: `c:\cygwin64\bin\find . -name '*.txt' -print0 | c:\cygwin64\bin\xargs -0 c:\cygwin64\bin\grep "interesting pattern" /dev/null` doesn't care about your fancy name. And that's only the first-pass tool.

Comment: The script's ineffectiveness aside, is such a thing even needed? Can't Windows 7 perform encryption on folders right away from folder options, even without Bitlocker? I think even Windows XP could already do that although I've never used it...

Comment: It looks like this is OP's source: https://operating-systems.wonderhowto.com/how-to/lock-folder-without-any-software-with-password-0150639/

Answer (score 85, accepted):

This batch script doesn't protect anything at all. It just renames the folder in question and sets the system and hidden attributes, which makes the folder a little bit harder to find and *might* keep your ten-year-old child from seeing it, but it won't stop anyone else.

At most, we might call this "security by obscurity", but I'm hesitant to even call it that, because in reality, setting the hidden and system attributes don't obscure that much.

There is no encryption going on at all – the folder doesn't get password-protected, the password is only used in the batch file to block someone from using the batch file to automatically remove the hidden and system attributes and rename the folder back to something sane.

> Would this be easy to crack after we export it into an `.exe` file?

Yes. Simply extract all strings from the `.exe` file and you'll find the "password".

> What if I encrypt the `.exe` file for extra security?

Again, the script does not provide any security at all. If you encrypt the batch/`.exe` file, you make it harder to use, but you don't actually make the folder in question more secure.

> What are those keys like `21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D`?

These don't mean anything by themselves (edit: see Bob and Danny's comments about junction points for an explanation of their meaning). They might be part of a larger system the batch file is part of, but they don't *add anything to the security of the actual folder* – it's just part of the folder's new name while it is "hidden".

#### What to do instead

You've already said it: Use BitLocker or VeraCrypt. Veracrypt can work with container files which will contain a whole tree of folders and it offers real security, as does BitLocker.

If you don't want to use any extra software, do what Mike suggests and zip the folder, protecting it with a password. This offers you nowhere near the security of BitLocker, VeraCrypt, and compatriots, though.

Comment: It looks like, at least on some versions of Windows, folders that follow a specific naming pattern (`Control Panel.{GUID}`) will open up a specific Control Panel applet rather than showing the contents. Of course, this is trivially defeated by renaming the folder (no password required), browsing with something other than Explorer (cmd, powershell, heck even your web browser...), etc..

Comment: There is also a workaround to use [container files with BitLocker](https://www.howtogeek.com/193013/how-to-create-an-encrypted-container-file-with-bitlocker-on-windows/)

Comment: Why do you say zipping the folder with a password offers nowhere near the security of BitLocker?  Winzip offers a choice of AES-128 and AES-256.

Comment: Because security isn't just about the strength of an encryption algorithm, it's about the whole system. So even if the zip encryption is strong (it used to be very weak, btw), the programmers wanted to develop a system that could compress files plus encrypt the result, not provide secure storage. So they most likely didn't think about things like sensitive data, including the encryption keys, getting paged out to disk, or about the system logging sensitive information to the system log, or about overwriting sensitive data with random bytes, etc etc.Providing secure encrypted storage is hard.

Comment: @MartinBonner "without any extra software". Default windows zip only supports ZipCrypto.

Comment: @MartinBonner because when viewing files from a password protected zip the plaintexts get copied into %tmp% on the harddrive; they do get deleted later but using normal delete instead of a secure erase.

Comment: Reminds me of older versions of windows where you could rename a folder in such a way that you couldn't access it. You could rename the folder back to something else and then you could get in.

Comment: Using a name followed by a dot and a GUID creates a sort of symbolic link from the file system to a Shell Object that is created by creating an instance of the class with this GUID using COM, which must implement the appropriate interface (IIRC [IShellItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761144(v=vs.85).aspx)). This is used mainly to create shortcuts to virtual items like "My Computer" or individual Control Panel apps.

Comment: _"These [hex strings] don't mean anything by themselves"_ - that's incorrect, they are [junction points](https://superuser.com/questions/993121/what-is-the-significance-of-windows-file-names-that-have-hex-numbers-in-them-lik/993179#993179).  Even if you can see hidden folders, if you attempt to open this folder, it will open the Control Panel instead. You'll need to rename the folder to actually open it.

Comment: Bob has already pointed this out, but I'll update the answer to refer to it.

Comment: Zip encryption security is not good... but it is probably adequate for the OPs needs, and it does accomplish his goal with existing tools on the system in ways that integrates well with the OS. Zip effectively answers the question as asked because it is so far superior to the method proposed by the OP: more secure, and less complicated.

Comment: @Joel - sure, it's probably good enough - but this is how Bruce Schneier puts it: There are systems that keep your little sister out of your private stuff, and others that keep everyone out. The latter are called "secure", the former aren't. So if you only worry about your little sister, Zip is an option. If you worry about someone willing to spend a few hundred dollars to hire an expert, it isn't. And it doesn't take all that much of an expert: Ratchet freak points out  a very easily exploited weakness of the zip solution.

Answer (score 20):

First off, you should read about [Kerchoff's Principle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle?wprov=sfla1):

> A cryptosystem should be secure even if everything about the system, except the key, is public knowledge.

The system you propose works (though I wouldn't use the word "secure") only as long as the code remains secret. Even if you "hid" the `.bat` code by renaming it to `.exe` and gave that file to any moderately-skilled hacker, they will open it in a text editor fancier than notepad and figure out what you've done in less than 30 seconds.

Instead, try turning it into a key-based system where you don't need to hide the code. For example, compress the folder into a password-protected ZIP and access it only in memory (i.e. in a zip viewer program) rather than extracting it to disk.

Comment: It's not secure even if the code remains a secret - this "protection" can be broken even accidentally, since any full disk scan/search will find matching documents if they're stored in this "hidden" folder.

Comment: @Peteris Let's say it works as long as the existence of the folder and its garbled name remain secret, which do appear to be goals of the system. It just uses really bad implementation to try to achieve them.

Comment: @jpmc26 no, it doesn't work - scanning *all* folders works even if "the existence of the folder and its garbled name remain secret"; the files inside and their contents are searchable, findable and will show up even accidentally if the user runs a search for something and the search (as it should) scans all folders on the drive, or (more likely) uses an index computed from all folders on the drive. Including ones the user didn't know about or that had weird, garbled names.

Comment: @Peteris If you scan everything and find the name of the folder, you know it exists and know the name of it and they are no longer secret. The fact that the implementation relies on them remaining secret (which would not happen in an attack or maybe even by accident, as you demonstrate) is why it's bad. That's how Kerchoff's Principle applies here; those are pieces of information other than the key.

Answer (score 10):

> Is it such a bad practice?

## Yes.

The batch file doesn't *use* the password to un-hide your folder, it just compares it and if it turns out correct, runs the "unlocking" commands. And there's nothing preventing you from running these commands *without checking the password*:

```
attrib -h -s "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}"
ren "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}" Private
```

Boom, the secret folder is "unlocked". No cracking needed.

Answer (score 7):

This doesn't even provide obscurity - regular Windows search will still search files inside a renamed and hidden folder. Just tested it out of curiosity.

No point even opening the exe file; just do the usual search for files of the right type - which is *exactly* what someone trying to steal your files would begin with (well, maybe right after your Documents), and it will pop out.

It's not even good for a .bat. If the goal was obscuring a file from computer-illiterate guests, but keeping it visible to all power users to it, you could move it to a partition with no letter assigned to it, calling it by GUID.

There are also fancier tricks to obscure a bat than turning it into an exe, like making it self-modifying, but nothing that provides security without encryption.

Answer (score 2):

This script just [sets the system and hidden flags](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-r2-and-2008/cc754186(v%3Dws.10)) of folder "Private" (`attrib +h +s`), which hides it from normal display in Windows Explorer and from a default listing on the commandline using `dir`, and furthermore renames the folder so that (if the first change does not prevent the user from seeing it), it is [not shown as a folder in Windows Explorer, but as the Control Panel](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/the-secret-behind-the-windows-7-godmode), which is the purpose of the the funny looking name part "{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}".

However, the first change can easily be circumvented by changing the Explorer option set to "show hidden files, folders, and drives". Actually, this is the setting on my computer. For the [`DIR` command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-r2-and-2008/cc755121%28v%3Dws.10%29), you would just have to use `DIR /a:HS` instead of purely `DIR` to show the folder.

And the second change only applies to Windows Explorer, not to the command line or any program that just lists files without using Windows Explorer. Note, however, that the file open or save dialogue shown in many applications also is a variant of Windows Explorer, behaving mostly the same.

Actually, you could do the attribute change yourself using the `attrib` command, and for the "hidden" attribute, but not the "system" attribute, also in the folder properties dialogue in Windows Explorer. And the renaming, of course you could do as well on the command line. And as you can do the changes, you can also revert them on the command line without needing to know any password.

So, in the end, this script only hides the folder from Windows Explorer or the file listing in default mode. But users with some technical knowledge can circumvent it. In fact, the password is only needed if you want to use this batch file to unhide the folder, but not if you just do that on the command line or in tools like third-party file managers yourself, so that is completely useless. And hence the discussion how to hide it is moot.